# R aggregate error: "replacement has <foo> rows, data has <bar>"

Tags: r

I'm attempting to aggregate a data frame and am getting an error I do not understand. I have a data frame called M15 that is 200k+ records of 33 variables. I cannot reproduce this error using data that I can share with the community.

```
M15<-M15backup[c(600:700),]

# setting the fields to roll up
aggField<-c('Location','EEStatus')

# group by rest of fields
byField<-setdiff(x=colnames(M15),y=aggField)

# example uses built in function, my production code uses a custom
M15.2<-aggregate(x=M15[aggField],
             by=M15[byField],
             FUN=length
             )
```

If I adjust the 600:700 in the first line I can get the script to run on small blocks of the data frame but if I run for the entire data frame I get an error of the form:

```
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, len + i, value = c("All Locations",  : 
  replacement has 341 rows, data has 394
```

Can somebody explain what this error means and/or suggest a way to deal with it?

Comment: Your `x` variable in `aggregate` can't have two columns. You need to combine them into one vector. `aggregate` will also be incredibly slow with this many rows. Use `data.table` or an SQL database.

Comment: My actual experience disagrees with your statement: "If I adjust the 600:700 in the first line I can get the script to run on small blocks of the data frame"

Comment: Additionally if I cut out one of the variables I'm aggregating by and run against the same subset of observations, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is apparently a bug with R before versions 3.0.3 as per [this bug report](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15004).  I had the same issue and upgraded R to version 3.1.2 and problem went away.