# R regex error replacement has x rows and data has y rows

Tags: regex, r

I am new to using R and I am trying to match a pattern. I added a new column POA where I want 1 when there is a match and 0 when there is no match for every record.

The function I used in R is:

```
Bribery$POA<-ifelse(grepl( "\\babuse of office\\b|\\babuse of power\\b|\\babuse of position\\b|\\bsquandering public funds\\b|\\bmisuse of power\\b|\\bmisuse of public funds\\b|\\babuse of trust\\b", Bribery$),1,0)
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "POA", value = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
>   :    replacement has 29 rows, data has 95292

Itl be great if anyone could tell me where I am going wrong

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814912/r-error-replacement-has-x-rows-data-has-y. Looks like regex is not the issue here. However, best is to just use a group and enclose it with `\b`s: `"\\b(abuse of office|babuse of power|abuse of position|squandering public funds|misuse of power|misuse of public funds|abuse of trust)\\b"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I used grouping the way you mentioned and I get the following error :Error in df$POA <- ifelse(grepl("\\b(abuse of office|abuse of power|abuse of position|squandering public funds|misuse of power|misuse of public funds|abuse of trust)\\b",  : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: You should definitely check the [MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and provide it to us.

Comment: What is `grepl` ?

Comment: Can you post a replicable example? What does `Bribery$` mean?  Can you just do the 'grepl' part without ifelse?