# R replacement has rows data has rows

Tags: r

I have a dataframe *df* w/ a column id, and a list *file_list*. I want to create a new column based on the position of a list using the value in the id column

```
df$new <- ""

for (i in df$id) {
       df$new[i] <- file_list[as.numeric(df$id[i])]
    }
```

I am getting an error similar to "replacement has x rows, data has y rows". I searched and found the below, and initialized my new column, but am still getting the error message.

[R Error - replacement has [x] rows, data has [y]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814912/r-error-replacement-has-x-rows-data-has-y)

Alternatively, if I can simply replace the id column with the new value from *file_list* that would work as well.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, it has been a few years since I touched R. Thanks in advance for pointers.

Comment: Your loop is `i %in% df$id` and then in the loop, you are subseting `df$id[i]`.  Either it should be `i in seq_along(df$id)` or inside the loop it is `as.numeric(i)`

Comment: can you show an example data set and desired output? e.g., reproducible example. it's hard to figure out what the problem is from code alone.

Comment: Thanks, used `seq_along()` and it works as intended now