# R: strsplit in each column; Error: replacement element 1 has [y] rows to replace 1 rows

Tags: r, strsplit

I'm working with a data frame (I'll call it 'letters') in R where there are 15 rows by 2 columns. Each column 2 contains a character string like "A|B|C|D|E". I want to split the string at each place a | appears to get the vector c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"). Here's my best idea of how to do this:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(letters)){
  letters[i,2] <- strsplit(letters[i,2], split = "[|]")
}
```

I get a similar error as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814912/error-replacement-has-x-rows-data-has-y) ("replacement has [x] rows, data has [y]"), and it seems to be trying to make a separate column for each index of the output vector. I'm sure this is a simple question, but I am new to R and stuck.

Comment: Try to run only `strsplit(letters[i,2], split = "[|]")` and check the output to debug

Comment: @Tung `> strsplit(letters[i,2], split = "[|]")` returns 
`[[1]]
[1] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D" "E"`

Answer (score 0):

Is `strsplit(letters[i,2], split = "[|]")[[1]]` what you're looking for? You won't be able to put that vector back in `letters[i,2]`, though as it has length 5 (instead of 1).

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for. I didn't realize that you can't store a vector in the cell of a data frame.

Comment: What would you suggest doing if what I'm trying to do in the end is ask: which rows contain "A"? Which contain "D"? and so I need a list associated with each row name?

Comment: Use `grepl("A", letters[[2]])` to determine if each value contains `"A"`.

Answer (score 0):

Your second column is (I think) a character vector. `strsplit`, as it mentions in the documentation (`?strsplit`) returns a list. Before we get into *why* your specific situation happened, some general advice:

1. Make a new column instead of replacing an existing one. This has the added benefit of not losing the original values.
2. Only replace values in a column with new values of the same class (e.g., character for character, integer for integer).

So I suggest adding a new column of split values:

```
letters[["splits"]] <- strsplit(letters[[2]], split = "|", fixed = TRUE)
```

You now have a list column, and each row of this column has a vector of the split letters from the original values.

### Why your problem happened

Let's dissect the assignment statement:

```
letters[i,2] <- strsplit(letters[i,2], split = "[|]")
```

On the left side of `<-` is `letters[i, 2]`, which is a `data.frame`. A `data.frame` stores all of its data in a list. R allows us to use this fact, especially in assignment. We can add or replace columns just like adding or replacing items in a list.

```
# This...
letters[, "one"] <- 1
letters[, "two"] <- 2
# is effectively the same as this
letters[, c("one", "two")] <- list(1, 2)
```

To the right of `->`, we have a call to `strsplit()`, which returns a `list`. As in the example just above, if you assign a list to a subset of a `data.frame`, it will be coerced into a `data.frame` itself. Each element of the list will be considered a column. So, the assignment plays out like this:

1. If `letters[i,2]` is `"A|B|C|D|E"`, then `strsplit(letters[i,2], split = "[|]")` is `list(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))`.
2. The assignment checks both sides, and sees the `data.frame` as a the "higher" type, so it coerces the list to a data.frame. The right side is now effectively `data.frame(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))`.
3. Now it tries to assign a `data.frame` with 1 column and *5 rows* to a subset with 1 column and *1 row*. Those dimensions don't match, so it takes what it can from the right side (just the first row) and warns you about what happened.

#### Why the suggested assignment works

So why isn't there any coercion in this?

```
letters[["splits"]] <- strsplit(letters[[2]], split = "|", fixed = TRUE)
```

The left side uses `[[` subsetting (treating the `data.frame` like a list) to add or replace the `"splits"` column. So no coercion is ever done.

Also, a `data.frame` can have a `list` as a column, just like a `list` can have a `list` as an element. A `data.frame` column just has to satisfy two things:

1. It has to be a vector.
2. Its length must be equal to the number of rows in the `data.frame` (recycling's attempted if necessary).

A `list` is a type of vector. And `strsplit()` returns a list the same length as its input, so both criteria are met.