# Error while using the slide() function from package DataCombine in R

Tags: r, slide

My data set is `mpa1` so I am using this code (with package DataCombine) to slide the `ttq` variable

```
library(DataCombine)
aa <- slide(mpa1,Var="ttq",slideBy=-1)
```

I am getting this error:

> Error in     `$[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , NewVar, value = list(NA, ttq
> = c(6L,  :
> replacement element 2 has 110898 rows, need 110899

The solution to a previous question question ([Error - replacement has [x] rows, data has [y]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814912/error-replacement-has-x-rows-data-has-y)) says to create a null variable first then run the code but it is also not working.

Here is a sample of my data:

```
open    high    low ltp ltq atp ttq num_trades
1331    1331    1331    1331    6   1331    6   1
1331    1331    1331    1331    2   1331    8   2
1331    1331    1331    1331    1   1331    9   3
1331    1331    1331    1331    1   1331    10  4
1331    1331    1331    1331    100 1331    110 5
1331    1331    1331    1331    41  1331    151 6
1331    1331    1331    1331    150 1331    301 7
1331    1331    1331    1331    50  1331    351 8
1331    1331    1331    1331    2   1331    353 9
1331    1331    1331    1331    15  1331    368 10
1331    1331    1331    1331    10  1331    378 11
1331    1331    1331    1331    44  1331    422 12
1331    1331    1331    1331    18  1331    440 13
1331    1331    1331    1331    4   1331    444 14
1331    1331    1331    1331    1   1331    445 15
1331    1331    1331    1331    1   1331    445 15
1331    1331    1331    1331    1   1331    445 15
1331    1331    1331    1331    1   1331    445 15
1331    1331    1331    1331    1   1331    445 15
1331    1331    1331    1331    1   1331    445 15
1331    1331    1331    1331    1   1331    445 15
1331    1331    1331    1331    1   1331    445 15
1331    1331    1331    1331    1   1331    445 15
1331    1331    1331    1331    1   1331    445 15
1331    1331    1331    1331    1   1331    445 15
1331    1331    1331    1331    1   1331    445 15
1331    1331    1331    1331    1   1331    445 15
```

Comment: If you say *"solution earlier"*, please include a link to that solution in the question.

Comment: here its told to create a null variable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814912/error-replace

Comment: Is your dataset named `mpa` or `mpa1`? Also, can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(mpa1)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(mpa1, 20))`.

Comment: open high low ltp ltq atp ttq num_trades
1331 1331 1331 1331 6 1331 6 1
1331 1331 1331 1331 2 1331 8 2
1331 1331 1331 1331 100 1331 110 5
1331 1331 1331 1331 41 1331 151 6
1331 1331 1331 1331 150 1331 301 7
1331 1331 1331 1331 50 1331 351 8
1331 1331 1331 1331 2 1331 353 9
1331 1331 1331 1331 15 1331 368 10
1331 1331 1331 1331 10 1331 378 11
1331 1331 1331 1331 44 1331 422 12
1331 1331 1331 1331 18 1331 440 13
1331 1331 1331 1331 4 1331 444 14
sample data . data set is mpa1. have edited the error

Comment: Please post the data **in the question**, as is it is very difficult for us to use it.