# How do you create a new character variable in R?

Tags: r, variables, character

In my data science class I have an assigned question to "use base R fuctions to create a variable called region in the data frame birth_data which takes the values Northeast, Midwest, South, and West."

Currently my code is

```
Northeast <- birth_data$state %in% c("CT", "ME", "MA", "NH", "RI", "VT", "NJ", "NY","PA")

Midwest <- birth_data$state %in% c("IL", "IN", "MI", "OH", "WI",
"IA", "KS", "MN", "MO", "NE", "ND", "SD")

South <- birth_data$state %in% c("DE", "DC", "FL", "GA", "MA", "NC", "SC", "VA", "WV", "AL", "KY", "MS", "TN", "AS", "LA", "OK", "TX")

West <- birth_data$state %in% c("AZ", "CO", "ID", "MO", "NV", "NM", "UT", "WY","AK", "CA", "HI", "OR", "WA")

birth_data$region <- c("Northeast","Midwest","South","West")
birth_data <- birth_data$region
```

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, region, value = c("Northeast", "Midwest", : replacement has 4 rows, data has 1103629

I am unsure of how to correct this issue but I know that it has to do with the vector length. Additionally, I am not sure how to assign variables for characters. If dplyr was allowed, I feel I would be more successful.

Comment: What other research was done? This looks useful https://www.gastonsanchez.com/r4strings/chars.html also https://stackoverflow.com/a/29815185/112233

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a more complex processing.

```
regions.vec <- c("Northeast", "Midwest", "South", "West")
regions <- birth_data[, regions.vec]

# for one row, use the binary vector row to select from regions.vec
process.row <- function(row) regions.vec[row]

# go through entire regions subdataframe and do this row by row
result <- list()
for (i in 1:dim(regions[1])) {
  result[[i]] <- process.row(regions[i, ])
}

# flatten the result list and add it to the rows of birth_data
birth_data$region <- unlist(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

At it's simplest you can do the following:

```
birth_data[Northeast, "region"] <- "Northeast"
birth_data[Midwest, "region"] <- "Midwest"
birth_data[South, "region"] <- "South"
birth_data[West, "region"] <- "West"
```

You can get fancier than this such as constructing the vector and then adding it to the `data.frame` but this gets the job done pretty quickly.