# Loop through all entries in one dataframe to find matches based on date criteria in another dataframe in R

Tags: r, loops, datetime, for-loop, dplyr

So I have a dataframe as follows called **df1**:

```
df1 <- structure(list(startTime = structure(c(1519903920, 1519905060, 
1519913740, 1519919880), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/New_York"), 
    endTime = structure(c(1519904880, 1519912200, 1519913940, 
    1522142880), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/New_York"), 
    impact = c(92.17, 616.43, 63.69, 14.69), impactPercent = c(184.15, 
    1495.17, 138.69, 19.97), impactSpeedDiff = c(3587.72, 25726.22, 
    2616.01, 474.11), maxQueueLength = c(5.76053, 5.76053, 4.829511, 
    2.447619), tmcs = list(c("110N04623", "110-04623", "110N04624", 
    "110-04624", "110N04625", "110-04625", "110N04626", "110-04626", 
    "110N04627"), c("110N04623", "110-04623", "110N04624", "110-04624", 
    "110N04625", "110-04625", "110N04626", "110-04626", "110N04627"
    ), c("110N04623", "110-04623", "110N04624", "110-04624", 
    "110N04625", "110-04625", "110N04626", "110-04626"), c("110N04623", 
    "110-04623", "110N04624", "110-04624", "110N04625")), early_startTime = structure(c(1519903620, 
    1519904760, 1519913740, 1522133400), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/New_York")), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")
```

And given this dataframe I need to match with the following dataframe (**df2**).

```
df2 <- structure(list(created_tstamp = structure(c(1519926899, 1519913840, 
1519913840, 1519927924, 1522141200, 1522152619, 1522152708, 1522152728, 
1519928416, 1519928785, 1519929080, 1519929306, 1519929964, 1519930050, 
1522154148, 1519930311, 1519930139, 1519930470, 1519930660, 1519929579
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/New_York"), 
    closed_tstamp = structure(c(1519929764, 1519926987, 1519927686, 
    1519928360, 1522152738, 1522152779, 1522154882, 1522152819, 
    1519928464, 1519928914, 1519929266, 1519929741, 1519939420, 
    1519930622, 1522155300, 1519930334, 1519931054, 1519951230, 
    1519930766, 1519930830), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/New_York"), 
    code = c("110-04508", "110N04623", "110N04623", "110P05583", 
    "", "", "110N04485", "110N04357", "110-05066", "110-04421", 
    "110N04421", "110P04577", "110-04204", "110-04269", "110+04673", 
    "110-04445", "", "110P05797", "110N04269", "110+04520")), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

A match is indicated by two criteria together:

1. `created_tstamp` in **df2** is between `early_startTime` and `endTime` in **df1**
2. `code` in `df2` exists in the same `tmcs` cell in `df1`

Both conditions need to be met for it to be considered a match. Ultimately I would like to create an identifier to match each row of **df2** to its corresponding match in **df1**. this is probably done with a loop of some sorts but I am unsure how to write it. Note: this is a subset of the data.

If a data point in **df2** doesn't have a match in **df1** it should be NA in the identifier column. and both df's should get an ID column in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work. Its hard to tell as it returns no matches with the provided data. This is because none of the `created_tstamp` are earlier than your `endTime`

Edit: now that we have a match with the updated question we can juggle the output as follows

```
test <- apply(df2,1, function(x) which(
    x[1] > df1$early_startTime & 
    x[1] < df1$endTime &
    grepl(x[3], df1$tmcs) &
    x[3] != ""
    ))


IDlist <- lapply(test,paste0,collapse=";")
df2$ID <- unlist(ifelse(lengths(test) > 0,IDlist, NA))
```

output:

```
> df2
        created_tstamp       closed_tstamp      code   ID
1  2018-03-01 12:54:59 2018-03-01 13:42:44 110-04508 <NA>
2  2018-03-01 09:17:20 2018-03-01 12:56:27 110N04623    2
3  2018-03-01 09:17:20 2018-03-01 13:08:06 110N04623    2
4  2018-03-01 13:12:04 2018-03-01 13:19:20 110P05583 <NA>
5  2018-03-27 05:00:00 2018-03-27 08:12:18           <NA>
6  2018-03-27 08:10:19 2018-03-27 08:12:59           <NA>
7  2018-03-27 08:11:48 2018-03-27 08:48:02 110N04485 <NA>
8  2018-03-27 08:12:08 2018-03-27 08:13:39 110N04357 <NA>
9  2018-03-01 13:20:16 2018-03-01 13:21:04 110-05066 <NA>
10 2018-03-01 13:26:25 2018-03-01 13:28:34 110-04421 <NA>
11 2018-03-01 13:31:20 2018-03-01 13:34:26 110N04421 <NA>
12 2018-03-01 13:35:06 2018-03-01 13:42:21 110P04577 <NA>
13 2018-03-01 13:46:04 2018-03-01 16:23:40 110-04204 <NA>
14 2018-03-01 13:47:30 2018-03-01 13:57:02 110-04269 <NA>
15 2018-03-27 08:35:48 2018-03-27 08:55:00 110+04673 <NA>
16 2018-03-01 13:51:51 2018-03-01 13:52:14 110-04445 <NA>
17 2018-03-01 13:48:59 2018-03-01 14:04:14           <NA>
18 2018-03-01 13:54:30 2018-03-01 19:40:30 110P05797 <NA>
19 2018-03-01 13:57:40 2018-03-01 13:59:26 110N04269 <NA>
20 2018-03-01 13:39:39 2018-03-01 14:00:30 110+04520 <NA>
```

Comment: Added an edit so there is in fact a match. This doesn't exactly work tho. I need to create a new column called "ID" where each row in df1 has an ID and then add an ID column to df2 which is the matching ID of df1 when there is a match and NA when there isnt

Comment: That's much closer! But when scaling to the actual data it doesn't work and i think it's because of how you generate the ID. ID is basically row number and thus we get an error. Instead, can it create a character ID for each row (ID001) and use that to write for df2$ID ? Error: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, ID, value = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 135L,  : 
  replacement has 10732 rows, data has 10728

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814912/error-replacement-has-x-rows-data-has-y

Comment: my code could possible run into trouble in the case where there are more matches than 1 for a row. If thats the case, you'd need to decide how it should be handled before `unlist`-ing

Comment: Right yeah duplicates are a real possibility. So If multiple rows in df2 match to the same row in df1, they should both have the same ID in the ID column in df2.

Comment: Updated OP to represent a duplicate

Comment: @JohnnyThomas I made a tweak, the type of duplicate you added was not an issue. I was worried about a duplicate the other way around (Which I think i've fixed)

Comment: So now, a majority of instances were the ID is listed in df2, there is a blank value for code. This shouldn't be the case since if code is not found in df1$tmcs, it is not a match.  Futhermore the collapse= ";" puts two IDs in one cell which doesn't exactly make sense. Each row in df2 only maps to 1 row of df1, but the rows of df1 can match multiple rows of df2.

Comment: I added a case where it is a blank tmc yet still returning an ID

Comment: @JohnnyThomas Just added a line that make a blank `code` fail to match every time. and removed the line that cathces double matches since you say it is not nessesary.

Comment: We have the problem still of replacement has x rows, data has y. as before. This wasn't a problem when you had the IDList

Comment: must be an multi-match somewhere, added it back in.

Comment: Good news it ran, but there's still a major issue. Some of the rows in df2 return something like 32;33, which should never be the case. Each row in df2 maps to exactly one entry in df1 but entries in df1 can map to several rows in df2. so there should never be multiple IDs in a cell in df2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216081/discussion-between-johnny-thomas-and-daniel-o).