# How to apply an operation to a specific Column in R

Tags: r

I have date in the first column and prices of a stock in the second column and I have imported this file in R as Y. I want the log differences of the closing prices while preserving the first column of date as is. I want to save the result as spReturns.

I came up with the following code:

```
spReturns = df <- transform(Y, Close = diff(log(Close)))
```

But, I am getting this error:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, inx[matched], value = list(Close = c(0.0100854932368533,  : 
  replacement element 1 has 1826 rows, need 1827
```

Comment: `diff` always returns a vector of size n - 1 because the difference between the first and previous value does not exist. You could do `diff(c(0, log(Close)))`. Depends on what you want as your first value.

Comment: Thank You. It works. But, it is giving me a very large first value. What if I want the first value to be 0.

Comment: You could use `c(NA, diff(log(Close))`

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64122317/680068

Comment: Got it. What if I want it to be 0 instead of NA. When I put c(0, diff(log(Close)), it assigns a very large value first up instead of 0.