# replacement has 12381021 rows, data has 12381022 in R

Tags: r, rows

I have run into an error:

**Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "EA", value = c("T", "A", "T", "T",  :
replacement has 12381021 rows, data has 12381022
Calls: $<- -> $<-.data.frame
Execution halted**

after loading the first of several files that need to go through the function (made to replace EA and/or OA using information from RSID if EA and OA are missing) found below. When I run the script on just a sample of the first file (first 5000 rows for instance) it works which is quite strange. So it only fails on the entire first file but not a sample of it. This might mean that the code works okay but not sure.

note1: the first file has 12381023 rows including the header.

note2: <-NA was performed before defining variables.

*Data (not all the columns onl the relevant ones)*

[image]

```
 RSID_match_replace <- function(x, EA, OA, RSID){
   RSID_vector1 <- unlist(strsplit(x[[RSID]], split=":"))
   A <- c("A")
   C <- c("C")
   T <- c("T")
   G <- c("G")
   if(x[[EA]]%in%RSID_vector1 & (!A%in%x[[OA]] | !C%in%x[[OA]] | !T%in%x[[OA]] | 
 !G%in%x[[OA]])) {
     return_EA <- x[[EA]]
     return_OA <- grep('A|C|T|G', RSID_vector1, value=TRUE)
     return_EA_exact <- paste0('^',return_EA,'$')
     return_OA <- grep(return_EA_exact, return_OA, value=TRUE, invert=TRUE)
   } else
   if(x[[OA]]%in%RSID_vector1 & (!A%in%x[[OA]] | !C%in%x[[OA]] | !T%in%x[[OA]] | 
  !G%in%x[[OA]])) {
       return_OA <- x[[OA]]
       return_EA <- grep('A|C|T|G', RSID_vector1, value=TRUE)
       return_OA_exact <- paste0('^',return_OA,'$')
      return_EA <- grep(return_OA_exact, return_EA, value=TRUE, invert=TRUE)
   } else {
     return_EA <- x[[EA]]
     return_OA <- x[[OA]]
   }
     return(list(return_EA,return_OA))
  }


 for (i in files){
   cat("Loading file",i,"\n")
   rsid.tmp  <- read.table(i, header = T, sep=" ", stringsAsFactors = F)
   cat("Initial\n")
   print(head(rsid.tmp))
   cat("\n")
   cat("Begin correcting EA and OA\n")
   output.df <- apply(rsid.tmp, 1, RSID_match_replace, "EA", "OA", "RSID")
   output.df <- do.call(rbind, output.df)
   rsid.tmp$EA <-NA
   rsid.tmp$OA <-NA
   rsid.tmp$EA <- unlist(output.df[,1])
   rsid.tmp$OA <- unlist(output.df[,2])
   cat("After correcting EA and OA\n")
   print(head(rsid.tmp))
   cat("\n")
   # Store new file
   new_file <- sub("(\\.txt)$", "_new\\1", i)
   cat("Storing new file:",new_file, "\n")
   write.table(rsid.tmp, new_file, quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
 }
```

Comment: Likely a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/29814912/3358272

Comment: Hello , I am not sure that it is a duplicate because in the code I have    rsid.tmp$EA <-NA
   rsid.tmp$OA <-NA      which is the answer to the link you provided but I still have the same error

Answer (score 0):

The problem was one row with unexpected information (likely error) in one column that could not be read by the script. Script was changed to account for this.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31896060)

Comment: @M.Viking: The fact that they are describing what the problem was suggests they found a solution, and thus this should _not_ be made as an edit to their question. It is correctly posted as an answer. Adding more detail would make this a more _useful_ answer, but that's a different matter.