# Can't change a character to a factor? Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Week, value = integer(0)) : replacement has 'x' rows, data has 'y'

Tags: r

I am trying to change a character to a factor using the code `Data$Week<-as.factor(Data$Week)`

It worked for the other components I was changing to a factor, but not for this one. This error appears:

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Week, value = integer(0)) :
replacement has 0 rows, data has 216

Why is this happenening?

Comment: You have to post a reproducible example for other to be able to help you, you can use `dput(head(Data))` and add it to your question. Also take a look at [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814912/error-replacement-has-x-rows-data-has-y) you may find your answer.

Comment: Greetings! Like the above user mentioned, its usually helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg