# Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, ride_length, value = numeric(0)) : replacement has 0 rows, data has 5667717

Tags: r

I am running the following code but getting an error.  How can I resolve it?

```r
all_trips$ride_length <- difftime(all_trips$endded_at, all_trips$started_at)
```

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, ride_length, value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 5667717
```

Comment: This is likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/29814912/3358272.

Comment: use `dput(all_trips)` in the console and paste the result to the question (or a subset of it) and you will have an answer promptly. There are multiple issues that could be present including data formatting and syntax errors in addition to spelling

Comment: Isn't there an extra d in `all_trips$endded_at`?