# Bad; what replacement has 12 rows, data has 10, how can i fix it

Tags: r

```
age = c("0-4","5-9","10-14","15-19","20-24","25-29","30-34","35-39","40-44","45-49","50-54","55-59","60-64","65-69","70-74","75-79","80+")  
mpop = c(8656, 11480, 10551, 10560, 11235, 13509, 13967, 17373, 17604, 18447, 18553, 15306, 11591, 7300, 4683, 4299, 3515)  
fpop = c(9107, 12400, 11444, 12693, 16268, 16303, 16673, 19114, 18288, 18158, 18100, 16854, 12646, 7163, 4320, 2673, 1729)   
fertility = c(0, 0, 0, 0.0009, 0.0518,  0.0837, 0.0362, 0.0057, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) 

m_survival = c(0.999339426, 0.99886684, 0.997980525, 0.997246828, 0.996224653, 0.99450419, 0.992854112, 0.988615374, 0.983382104, 0.975700168, 0.964435944, 0.950906784, 0.917665731, 0.855619556, 0.749899982, 0.594425903, 0.408440629)  
f_survival = c(0.999596691, 0.999650726, 0.999114461, 0.998046471, 0.997269372, 0.996112941, 0.995878842, 0.99545672, 0.992673446, 0.990217526, 0.986850727, 0.981502561, 0.967477422, 0.938167078, 0.870952018, 0.740637905, 0.552898971)


m_netmigration = c(0.003, -0.147, -0.044, -0.192, -0.468, -0.354, 0.023, -0.176, -0.118, -0.94, -0.159, -0.122, -0.058, -0.048, -0.005, 0.001, 0.012)  
f_netmigration = c(0.011, -0.147, -0.105, -0.309, -0.975, -0.340, -0.075, -0.069, -0.140, -0.078, -0.168, -0.1, -0.07, -0.002, 0.016, 0.023, 0.028)  
sex_ratio <- 106.6   
interval <- 5  


projection_period <- seq(2020, 2040, by=5)  
predictions_cohorts<- matrix(NA, nrow = length(age), ncol = length(projection_period), dimnames = list(age, projection_period))  
predictions_cohorts[, 1] <- mpop + fpop  
predictions_cohorts  


for (i in 2:length(projection_period)) {
  
  m_0_4 <- sum(fertility * fpop * interval)*(sex_ratio/(100+sex_ratio)) * m_survival[1]
  m_other <- mpop * m_survival
  m_other[length(m_other)-1] <- m_other[length(m_other)-1]+m_other[length(m_other)]
  m_other <- m_other[-length(m_other)]
  mpop <- c(m_0_4, m_other) * (1+m_netmigration)
  
  f_0_4 <- sum(fertility * fpop * interval)*(100/(100+sex_ratio)) * f_survival[1]
  f_other <- fpop * f_survival
  f_other[length(f_other)-1] <- f_other[length(f_other)-1]+f_other[length(f_other)]
  f_other <- f_other[-length(f_other)]
  fpop <- c(f_0_4, f_other) * (1+f_netmigration)  
  
  predictions_cohorts[, i] <- mpop + fpop
}


predictions_cohorts  


predictions$cohort[8:12] <- apply(predictions_cohorts, 2, sum)  


plot(predictions$year, predictions$observation, type = "l", col = "black", lwd = 2,
     xlab = "Year", ylab = "Population",
     ylim = c(min(predictions$observation, na.rm = TRUE), max(growth_limit)),
     main = "Population Projection Comparison")  

lines(predictions$year, predictions$linear, col = "red", type = "b")  
lines(predictions$year, predictions$geometric, col = "blue", type = "b")  
lines(predictions$year, predictions$parabolic, col = "green", type = "b")  
lines(predictions$year, predictions$modified_geometric, col = "purple", type = "b")  
lines(predictions$year, predictions$gompertz, col = "orange", type = "b")  
lines(predictions$year, predictions$logistic, col = "pink", type = "b")  
lines(predictions$year, predictions$cohort, col = "brown", type = "b")  

points(predictions$year, predictions$observation, pch = 19, col = "black", cex = 1.5)  

legend("topleft", 
       legend = c("Observation", "Linear", "Geometric", "Parabolic", "Modified geometric", "Gompertz", "Logistic", "Cohort"),
       col = c("black", "red", "blue", "green", "purple", "orange", "pink", "brown"), lty = 1)
```

In this case, 'predictions$cohort[8:12] <- apply(predictions_cohorts, 2, sum)' an error comes out like this 'Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, cohort, value = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  :
replacement has 12 rows, data has 10'. how can i fix it?

To solve the problem, 'predictions$cohort[8:12] <- apply(predictions_cohorts, 2, sum)' > 'predictions$cohort[8:10] <- apply(predictions_cohorts, 2, sum)' but it doesn't work

I really don't know [8:10] meaning about

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/29814912/3358272

Comment: If you are asking a question about `data.frame`s and a row-replacement error, why do you make the question appear more complicated by adding plotting code?

Answer (score 0):

That error is a red herring ... you have other problems *first*.

1. When I run your code, I get `Error: object 'predictions' not found`. Since you aren't getting this error, then it seems that you are working on a different object named `predictions` in your environment. I'll assume `predictions_cohorts`.
2. You are assigning to `[8:12]`, but I don't see immediately exactly what should be happening there. However ...

   The return value from `apply(...)` is a numeric vector length 5, which is the number of columns you have in `predictions_cohorts`. But it's not clear to which *row* you want this added. **But** since you use `sum`, I think you mean to add a row to the end, in which case we can `rbind` it:

   ```r
   predictions_cohorts <- rbind(predictions_cohorts, apply(predictions_cohorts, 2, sum))
   predictions_cohorts
   #         2020       2025       2030       2035        2040
   # 0-4    17763  14748.714   7807.317   2370.359    423.5129
   # 5-9    23880  15143.829  12573.916   6656.075   2020.8337
   # 10-14  21995  22056.567  13993.406  11638.879   6161.1082
   # 15-19  23253  16408.793  16499.018  10478.081   8750.9342
   # 20-24  27503   5919.158   4710.924   4880.916   3134.0172
   # 25-29  29812  17937.971   3813.975   3034.653   3143.9647
   # 30-34  30640  28765.414  17222.053   3860.248   3074.9357
   # 35-39  36487  26885.159  25171.457  15165.465   3179.0599
   # 40-44  35892  31511.897  23197.485  21727.498  13078.5279
   # 45-49  36605  17776.687  15870.288  12700.217  11491.1783
   # 50-54  36653  30096.609  14642.094  13071.964  10461.2746
   # 55-59  32160  31786.010  26104.243  12969.327  11579.7122
   # 60-64  24237  29094.701  28746.435  23609.432  11826.0673
   # 65-69  14463  22336.354  26831.844  26462.295  21740.4850
   # 70-74   9003  13042.405  20259.311  24355.756  23971.2975
   # 75-79   6972   7364.344  10748.426  16840.932  20269.5893
   # 80+     5244   7056.886   8430.025  11642.796  17728.0143
   #       412562 337931.496 276622.214 221464.893 172034.5130
   ```

   Optionally adding a row-name to it:

   ```r
   rownames(predictions_cohorts)[nrow(predictions_cohorts)] <- "TOTAL"
   ```