# Cannot export or save workbook with openxlsx2 in R

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx2

I'm trying to export my workbook object with openxlsx2 package, but I got an error message as following.

```
dat2 = wb_load("data.xlsx" ,data_only = F, calc_chain = T)
num =  c(600000,12340)
dat2 = dat2 %>% wb_add_data(sheet = 1, x = num, dims = "E17")
wb_save(dat2, file = 'QQQ.xlsx', overwrite = F)

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, tmpDirPartName, value = "C:\\Users\\nergul18\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpCKmbVx\\workbookTemp_b0cc4801ed2/xl/worksheets/") : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

What does this error mean and How do I handle this one?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. `R version 4.2.3, openxlsx2_1.0`

Comment: What is `"data.xlsx"`? I just tested with a spreadsheet of my own, and it also worked without error. Linux, R-4.3.1, openxlsx2-1.1

Comment: As for that error, it's based on https://stackoverflow.com/q/29814912/3358272. Because of the reference to `tmpDirPartName` (and https://github.com/JanMarvin/openxlsx2/blob/ee9edb46e8b9bc2169e9b0d672e491dca227d77b/R/class-workbook.R#L2510), it seems likely that this is a bug in the package. I suggest you [open a new bug report](https://github.com/JanMarvin/openxlsx2/issues/new/choose), where it will be even more important to make this reproducible, either by providing `data.xlsx` that generates the error, or creating an `xlsx` file programmatically that triggers the error. Good luck!

Comment: As author of the package I second r2evans suggestion. If there is a problem, please make it reproduce able and open an issue. And please do not use the `calc_chain` option. Setting this has the tendency to brick your file!

Comment: I've opened an issue [here](https://github.com/JanMarvin/openxlsx2/issues/832). It might be that OPs input file is somehow incomplete. Lacking either `workbook.xml.rels` or `Content_Types`. I wasn't aware that either case is possible.