# Error in data.frame(channel_id = channel.df$id, title = channel.df$snippet.title, : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

Tags: r, error-handling, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am working on this project with youtube API. The following is my code to retrive the data from the api url

```r
for (channel_id in channel_ids) {
  api_params1 <-
    paste(paste0("key=", key),
          paste0("id=", channel_id),
          "part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics",
          sep = "&")
  api_call1 <- paste0(base, "channels", "?", api_params1)
  api_result1 <- GET(api_call1)
  json_result1 <- content(api_result1, "text", encoding = "UTF-8")
  channel.json <- fromJSON(json_result1, flatten = TRUE)
  print(paste("Structure of channel.df for channel ID", channel_id, ":"))
  str(channel.json)
  channel.df <- channel.json$items
  print(paste("Column names for channel ID", channel_id, ":"))
  print(names(channel.df))
  if ("items" %in% names(channel.json) && length(channel.json$items) > 0) {
    channel.df <- channel.json$items
    standardized_df <- data.frame(
      channel_id = channel.df$id,
      title = channel.df$snippet.title,
      description = channel.df$snippet.description,
      published_at = channel.df$snippet.publishedAt,
      country = channel.df$snippet.country,
      view_count = channel.df$statistics.viewCount,
      subscriber_count = channel.df$statistics.subscriberCount,
      hiddensub_count = channel.df$statistics.hiddenSubscriberCount,
      video_count = channel.df$statistics.videoCount
    )
    channel_data_list[[channel_id]] <- standardized_df
  }
}

all_channel_data <- do.call(rbind, channel_data_list)
print(all_channel_data)
```

but i am getting this error which is limiting me to get the dataframe out of my code

```
Error in data.frame(channel_id = channel.df$id, title = channel.df$snippet.title, :
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

I tried using if condition but it seems to be not helping out.

Comment: I fixed a typo in the code (missing a leading quote around `":"` inside a `print(paste(..))`, I hope that's alright. It seemed safe since the error you report is unrelated and after that point.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Just_an_avg_human! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (you have this), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: This is likely related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/29814912/3358272, even though the error message itself is different. I don't know which is wrong (we don't have your data). When the error hits, first look at `channel_id` to know which of the ids is causing a problem. From there, check each of your frame arguments (e.g., `channel.df$id`) to see which one is _empty_, and then step back to find out why it is empty.

Comment: Side note: your whole call to `data.frame(..)` is pulling values from what is likely a named `list`. You can probably simplify that `data.frame` call to `as.data.frame(channel.df[c("id","snippet.title",...)])` or similar.