# subtract column1 (dataframe1) from column2 (dataframe2) based on matching column in both R

Tags: r, dataframe, matching

`Dataframe1` has two columns: num_movies and userId. `Dataframe2` has two columns: No_movies and userId. But `Dataframe2` has 2106 rows and `Dataframe1` has 1679 rows. I want to subtract the number of movies in `Dataframe2`  from `Dataframe1` based on matching userId values. I have written the following line:

```
df1$num_movies = df1$num_movies - df2$No_movies[df1$userId %in% df2$userId]
```

and I get the following error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "num_movies", value = c(2, 9, 743,  : 
  replacement has 2106 rows, data has 1679
In addition: Warning message:
In df1$num_movies - df2$No_movies[df1$userId %in%  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

[Elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353512/r-aggregate-error-replacement-has-foo-rows-data-has-bar) it has been proposed that I upgrade from 3.0.2 to 3.1.2 to solve this problem. But I still have the same error after the upgrade. What I have written seems logical for me. I intend to pick only 1679 userIds out of 2106. Why is it selecting all of them? How do I circumvent this error?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example

Comment: As the error indicates, you are subtracting two vectors that are not of the same length.  It may be possible that all the elements in `df1$userId` are not in `df2$userId` resulting in different lengths after subsetting

Comment: It looks like you have df1 and df2 the wrong way round in your brackets, as you seem to be taking df2 elements based on df1 indices. You could try `[df2$userId %in% df1$userId]` but this method will still only work if there are no IDs unique to df2 (it looks like there aren't) and the IDs will need to be in the same order in both sets. It might be safer to make a merged dataset using `merge`.

Comment: *no IDs unique to df1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `match` function to find the corresponding row from `Dataframe2` for each row in `Dataframe1`.

```
matched.movies <- Dataframe2$No_movies[match(Dataframe1$userId, Dataframe2$userId)]
matched.movies[is.na(matched.movies)] <- 0
Dataframe1$num_movies <- Dataframe1$num_movies - matched.movies
Dataframe1
#   num_movies userId
# 1         10      1
# 2          7      2
# 3          6      3
```

Data:

```
(Dataframe1 <- data.frame(num_movies=rep(10, 3), userId=1:3))
#   num_movies userId
# 1         10      1
# 2         10      2
# 3         10      3
(Dataframe2 <- data.frame(No_movies=2:6, userId=c(0, 2, 3, 9, 10)))
#   No_movies userId
# 1         2      0
# 2         3      2
# 3         4      3
# 4         5      9
# 5         6     10
```